# 2 decimal places in Java, Just started doing Java in class last week

Tags: java, decimal

Started taking a Java class at school and doing extra credit 
and need help figuring out how to just have 2 decimal places.
Thank you for the help.
Christopher

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChapterTwoEx8 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

```
//Create a Scanner object to read keyboard input.
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


//Declare Constants
  final double SALES_TAX_RATE = 0.07;
  final double TIP = 0.15;

//Declare Variables
   double yourMealsPrice;
   double wifeMealsPrice;
   double sum;
   double tip;
   double totalCostOfMeal;
   double salesTax;


 //Get the prices of the meals.
     System.out.println("Please enter the price of your wives meal.");
     wifeMealsPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("Please enter the price of your meal.");
     yourMealsPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();

  //Calculate cost of the meals.
     sum = (double) wifeMealsPrice + yourMealsPrice;

  //Calcute the sales tax
     salesTax = (double) sum * SALES_TAX_RATE;

  //Calcute tip
     tip = (double) sum * TIP;

  //Calcute total cost of meal
     totalCostOfMeal = (double) sum + tip + salesTax;

  System.out.println("Your meals were $ " + sum); 
  System.out.println("The total tax you paid is $ " + salesTax);
  System.out.println("The tip you should leave is $ " + tip);
  System.out.println("The amount of money you paid to keep your wife happy this night is $ " + totalCostOfMeal);






       }
```

}

Comment: Firstly, you should not use doubles (or floats) fro money. Use BigDecimal. This also provides rounding and formatting.  But in in general to print to 2 dp try using `System.out.printf`

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I will try and figure out how to edit the non pertinent info out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NumberFormat`

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String formattedSum = nf.format(sum);
System.out.println("Your meals were $ " + formattedSum); 
System.out.println("The total tax you paid is $ " + nf.format(salesTax));
System.out.println("The tip you should leave is $ " + nf.format(tip));
System.out.println("The amount of money you paid to keep your wife happy this night is $ " + nf.format(totalCostOfMeal));
```

Or, you could get rid of the dollar signs and just use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`
instead of using `NumberFormat.getInstance();`